# Synchronizing GnuPG private keys between multiple servers for horizontal scaling

Tags: centos7, gnupg, clustering-key

I am using CentOS 7 and GnuPG 2.0 for one of my applications which is using encryption and decryption.

Now I am trying to scale my application horizontally, on two server named as server A and server B.

Let's say the application creates a private/public key pair on server A, how can I share the same set in server B or vice versa, so that application can access same set of keys from either servers?

Answer (score 1):

Given you do not describe any method which does not store the locally, you're probably using a normal GnuPG home directory with the private key stored in the keychain. Just export this key (`gpg --export-secret-keys <key-id>`) and then import it (`gpg --import`) using the same mechanics for distributing other credentials (database, ...).

GnuPG keys do not change "on their own", usually are long-lasting and creation is often a manual process; so you don't need to actively monitor and synchronize them. Just roll out the new copy in the rare case they actually change. Again -- compare the process to database passwords or other secrets.

If keys are actually regenerated regularly, you will have to run the export-import-process whenever creating new keys (and be sure to consider timing issues with the synchronization process not being finished yet, but access is already spread among the servers).

A (much more complex and error-prone, if you don't know the technology in detail) alternative is to use a `gpg-agent` socket shared over the network, for example by using SSH tunnels or similar solutions. This allows all connected servers to *use* the private key, without having it stored locally. This might especially prove important if you cannot (may not) store the private key locally. Using `gpg-agent` socket sharing, the private key is never leaving the server running `gpg-agent`, which performs all private key operation (the major parts for handling encryption is usually formed by the symmetric encryption of the actual data, but make sure you don't run into scaling issues!).

Comment: Thanks Jens, Import/Export of keys is a alternative solution i have in batch, But Currently I am looking for some automated solution, seems like gpg-agent can handle this. Could to share more on gpg-agent and any guide for implementation.

Comment: Is this process is same as Export/Import Keys: (Assume I Have daily key Creation.)
scp ~/.gnupg/pubring.gpg root@xx.xx.xx.xx:~/.gnupg/pubring.gpg
scp ~/.gnupg/secring.gpg root@xx.xx.xx.xx:~/.gnupg/pubring.gpg
scp ~/.gnupg/trustdb.gpg root@xx.xx.xx.xx:~/.gnupg/pubring.gpg

Comment: This will work for sure -- but make sure to stop the application and `gpg-agent` while copying the files.

Comment: Exporting `gpg-agent`'s socket is too involved to be in scope for a Q&A here. Look at `man gpg-agent` and the notes on the `extra-socket`, and consider a solution to make a socket remotely accessible (this depends on your local setup and software in use). Configuring GnuPG to use this socket is a rather easy task, but also make sure to properly start and keep running `gpg-agent` (for example, by writing your own systemd unit file).